# How to write mysql table data to an excel file but no downlad just store the file

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I want to send the xls file as an attachment.
For that I need to store the xls file at some location and then send it as attachment.
The xls file data is basically fetched from a mysql table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write mysql query results to csv file format. It's xls compatible.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM table');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$fp = fopen('/tmp/file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($row as $val) {
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}

fclose($fp);
```